# Cypress pipe console.log and command log to output

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

Is it possible to redirect or capture Cypress browser log and command log to output?

I read some Cypress github [issues](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/448) on this topic. But I don't know how to make it work.

Basically, I want to capture all the Cypress GUI command logs in the headless non-GUI mode. If I can include browser console log will be even better. The purpose is to understand what happened when a test fails.

I use teamcity as ci. Here is an example of my build log. I want to see all the command log here too. Actually, any console.log run on the server side using `cy.task` is displayed in the build log. Running `cy.task('log',message)` is too manual. Any smarter ways?

```
[09:49:08][Step 1/1] 2 of 4: new actions (52s)
[09:50:00][Step 1/1] 3 of 4: new actions (52s)
[09:50:53][Step 1/1] 4 of 4: new actions (53s)
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   (Results)
[09:51:47][Step 1/1] 
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   ┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Tests:        8                     │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Passing:      8                     │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Failing:      0                     │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Pending:      0                     │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Skipped:      0                     │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Screenshots:  0                     │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Video:        true                  │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Duration:     3 minutes, 38 seconds │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Estimated:    1 minute, 8 seconds   │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   │ Spec Ran:     action/action_spec.js │
[09:51:47][Step 1/1]   └─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: It looks like they are trying to produce an all-encompassing feature rather than a simple hook, which is what most people seem to want. jantoebe's code [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/448#issuecomment-393486805) looks promising. Might be worth asking him where he adds it in the tests.

Comment: How about sending client's browser log back to the server? Using jantoebe's idea of replacing `console` and somehow send the log back to node's console log. Do I need to make an endpoint to listen on a port using `cy.task`?

Comment: Use something like this https://github.com/krakenjs/beaver-logger. It might be an overkill.

Comment: Yes, definitely a `cy.task` to run the code into Node env. Then just fs to a file, but with some nice formatting. I am also interested in capturing the command log formatted html (not just the test) for documentation, so `document.getElementById('root').innerHTML` looks like the way to do that.

Comment: Please also see [cypress-failed-log](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-failed-log) which enumerates the commands - looks quite useful for CI scenario.

Answer (score 104):

As of Cypress 3.0.0, you can use `cy.task()` to access node directly and output to the node console. From the docs:

```js
// in test
cy.task('log', 'This will be output to the terminal')
```

```js
// in plugins file
on('task', {
  log (message) {
    console.log(message)
    return null
  }
})
```

See [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html) for more info.

I don't know of a way to mirror the Cypress logs to the console directly, but this is at least a workable alternative.

Comment: Somehow this is not working for me. I'm on latest Cypress version.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta This answer was taken directly from [the doc page for `cy.task`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html). If you follow the steps from the latest documentation and it doesn't work, then you may have found a bug, which you can [report on Github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new).

Answer (score 32):

Setting the [`ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/environment-variables#electron_enable_logging) environment variable to `1` will cause all Chrome internal logging to be printed to the console.

```shell
ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 npx cypress run
```

> ### [`ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/environment-variables#electron_enable_logging)
>
> Prints Chrome's internal logging to the console.

With this enabled, in addition to capturing any existing logging, this will also allow you to manually log within a test using `console.log`:

```javascript
console.log('Response JSON: ' + json)
```

Comment: Too bad that this only works when tests run in electron, and not e.g. when using chrome (`ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 npx cypress run --browser chrome`)

Comment: @LGenzelis even with electron its not working for me

Comment: hey @wamster , check my answer. Or just go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-terminal-report. It's been a game changer for me :)

Answer (score 10):

**FYI:**

Cypress community is going to provide native support so that we don't have to do any workarounds to print the logs on non-GUI(headless) CLI.

Ongoing issue: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/448 includes reference to 3 existing workarounds https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/448#issuecomment-613236352

Comment: Sadly, they decided to only fix it for cloud customers :(

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on @Joshua-wade's answer, you can overwrite `cy.log` to redirect all calls to it to the log task. Just as the following:

`Cypress.Commands.overwrite('log', (subject, message) => cy.task('log', message));`

Note: there's a small drawback to this: when you run the test using the Test Runner, instead of seeing `LOG    my message` in the command log, you'll see `TASK    log, my message`. But IMHO it's negligible.

Comment: when i try this i get `The 'task' event has not been registered in the setupNodeEvents method. You must register it before using cy.task()` - ```Cypress:        10.7.0```

Answer (score 3):

```js
// cypress.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: "cnpkrh",
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        log(message) {
          console.log(message);
          return null;
        },
      });
    },
  },
});


// cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js
cy.task('log', 'This will be output to the terminal')
```

Comment: This is a very good alternative and worked for me. Especially simply using: ```cy.task('log', 'This will be output to the terminal')``` anywhere in the code.

Comment: A good followup to this is to override the log function if in headless mode.  See hughsk's answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73827995/5327131

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Araon's approach using overwrite on the log function. Another approach, if you want to keep cy.log the default behavior, would be create a custom command. Doc [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Syntax)

Example:
`Cypress.Commands.add("printLog", (message) => { cy.task("log", {message}); })`

This way you can call function `printLog` vs `cy.task("log", {message});`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am the plugin author

You can capture Cypress CI GUI commands in headless mode, together with all the network requests, browser console messages and DOM tree changes using this free open-source plugin: https://github.com/currents-dev/cypress-debugger

As an alternative, you can also use a set of other well-known plugins:

- https://github.com/archfz/cypress-terminal-report to print the browser log messages and cypress steps to terminal
- https://github.com/NeuraLegion/cypress-har-generator to capture network requests as a file