# How do I save Cypress's testrunner's "console log" (left hand side) to a file

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I would like to save the data from the left-hand-side of the TestRunner to a text file (json, plain text, or any kind of text).

I feel like this should be very easy, and that I'm simply just missing something.  However, I cannot find anything to explain this.   I have checked this other S.O. question:  [Cypress pipe console.log and command log to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070262/cypress-pipe-console-log-and-command-log-to-output), which references this [currently open issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/448) -- but this appears to be focused on collecting the *browsers* console log.

I even tried one of the workarounds suggested in the discussion of that open issue, [cypress-log-to-output](https://github.com/flotwig/cypress-log-to-output) - but that put a *ton* of output in the terminal from which I launched the test.  I did try to correlate the extra output to the relatively few entries from the TestRunner's left-hand-side, but did not see anything to match them up.

I'm just hoping to get a text file that looks like this (with perhaps a bit of detail for each entry):

```
1 visit /
(xhr) GET 200 /todos
2 wait @todos
(req) GET /todos Received todos
...
```

Or perhaps JSON.

My motivation comes from having to write Cypress tests for our CI that will be testing a very old AjaxSwing based application that makes heavy use of XHR requests, and it can be a different number of XHR requests for each test run (sometimes 8, sometimes 12 just to load the first page).

The AjaxSwing app is not changing, so I have to figure this out as best as possible.  So I wanted to see a whole text file with all the information from the TestRunner's left hand side.    Perhaps even compare separate runs to see if I can spot some "header" or "body" value I could use to distinguish the *right* XHR request to wait for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

One approach using the `log:added` event

```js
// top of spec
const logs = []
Cypress.on('log:added', (log) => {
  const message = `${log.consoleProps.Command}: ${log.message}`
  logs.push(message)
})

it('writes to logs', () => {

  ...  // some commands that log

  cy.writeFile('logs.txt', logs)
});
```

Comment: small improvement: `const message = log.event ? \`${log.consoleProps.Event}: ${log.consoleProps.URL}\` : \`${log.consoleProps.Command}: ${log.message}\``