# Print DOM/HTML contents to console on headless Cypress failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

My [Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/) tests are failing to find some elements in the DOM, but only when running headless on our CI server (it works when running locally, headless or not). I also can't see anything obviously wrong in the generated screenshots and video recording.

How can I print the current HTML contents of all or some part of the DOM to the console using Cypress? (Ideally only when a test fails, but that's not critical)

Answer (score 0):

### Log HTML

Cypress [automatically includes the jQuery](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$) library and exposes it's methods - this includes [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) which can give you an element's HTML content as a string. If you have [console.log() set-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070262/cypress-pipe-console-log-and-command-log-to-output) (also see below) then you can then print an element's HTML string to the console with `console.log()`, e.g.:

```js
cy.get('body').invoke('html').then((val) => console.log(JSON.stringify(val)))
```

### Log only on test failures

If you don't want to flood your test output all the time and only want to print that HTML when a test fails, you can [bind to Cypress events](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events.html#Binding-to-Events) such as 'fail' with `cy.on('fail', ...)` within the specific tests. If you want this automatically for all tests, then you can rather use `Cypress.on('fail', ...)` which you would need to put in your [supportFile](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#e2e), possibly as follows:

```js
/**
 * Place in supportFile, e.g. cypress/support/e2e.js
 */

// Setup code to run before each test
Cypress.on('fail', (err, runnable) => {
    // always print the full page DOM whenever an error occurs
    console.log(Cypress.$('body').html())
    // re-throw error so test still fails
    throw err
})
```

### Console logging

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070262/cypress-pipe-console-log-and-command-log-to-output) for more details on logging to the console in Cypress. A quick summary of what worked for me was to add the following to my `cypress.config.js`:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    // Other settings
    ...
    // Enable console.log() in tests
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        on('task', {
          log(message) {
            console.log(message)
            return null
          }
        })
    },
  }
})
```

However, `console.log()`'s output won't necessarily be output to the  terminal, so you might need to set the `ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING` environment variable to `1`, e.g. you could run Cypress as follows:

```bash
ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=1 npx cypress run
```