# How can I see `cy.log` output when using Cypress headlessly?

Tags: cypress

When running Cypress headlessly, I can see `console.log` output from the frontend code under test by using the `DEBUG` environment variable, like:

```
DEBUG='cypress:launcher' npx cypress run --browser chrome
```

However, I haven't found any similar way to see the output of `cy.log` from the Cypress test code when running headlessly. Even with `DEBUG='cypress:*'` I don't see them - they only seem to be visible in the interactive interface. It feels like there must be some way to see the `cy.log` output headlessly - can someone help with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress pipe console.log and command log to output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070262/cypress-pipe-console-log-and-command-log-to-output)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first step is to add a new task in your Cypress config file so that you can run `console.log` from Node:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on("task", {
        log(args) {
          console.log(...args);
          return null;
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Then, you can override `cy.log` so that it calls this task whenever you run the command in headless mode, and `console.log` when you're running in headed mode. You can do this by adding the following to your commands file:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("log", function(log, ...args) {
  if (Cypress.browser.isHeadless) {
    return cy.task("log", args, { log: false }).then(() => {
      return log(...args);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(...args);
    return log(...args);
  }
});
```

Comment: I've added this to my code, but what value should I assigned to the DEBUG variable to see the cy.log output?

Answer (score 0):

I can see the output of cy.log by using DEBUG=cypress.server.task.
I used it to get a log of the headers of a sent request when running in headless mode.

Although I first tried the solution of @hughsk, I noticed that I could to without it; just using DEBUG suffices for me.
Because we also have code coverage running as a task, this will still generate a lot of logging, after which it is a bit tedious to find the cy.log task that your are interested in. In that case, you can redirect the output to a file and then use a text editor to search for it.

In Linux/Unix, the DEBUG output is going to the error output, so you'll have to use '2>' to redirect it to a file.

Like this:

```
DEBUG='cypress:server:task' npx cypress run --browser=chrome 2> DEBUG_cypress-server-task.log
```