# How do I get console.logs to log to the terminal in VS code when running a react server?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, visual-studio-code

Super noob question here but I completely forgot how to do this. When running my React app with a node server, I can't get anything to log in the terminal.

I have a Cypress config file that looks like this:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: 'some id',
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  retries: 3,
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      console.log('hey there') 
    },
  },
});
```

However, when I look at the terminal, it just gives me this message that my app is running in local host:

[image]

What do I need to do to view the `console.log('hey there')`? I can't scroll up in the terminal.

Comment: I think this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070262/cypress-pipe-console-log-and-command-log-to-output?